# How to create a RecyclerView horizontal with a wrap_content width and not scrollable?

Tags: java, android

I want to achieve that my `RecyclerView` will display or add the item from left to right and when it reaches the end of the screen the added item will display on the next line like this.

[image]

and not like this

[image]

here is my code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:itemCount="10" />
```

I also tried using the `StaggeredLayoutManager` and `Vertical` orientation (Since as I said, I want to add the item from left to right) but using a `Span` I do not want to align the items like a `Grid`. Also the Column Count is not fix and it may be depends on the screen size.

any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FlexboxLayout.

Please follow the link.

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is a bit misleading, but I've used `com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup` successfully with a list of `ViewSwitcher` inside it. For the record it also worked with a list of `MaterialButton`.

It does have the UI behavior you want, but it's not related to `RecyclerView` so you have to do some coding if you're expecting the same API, I'd recommend extending your own `MyWrappableView: ChipGroup`.